# fullcalendar businessHours on non-working days in agendaDay view with resources

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

How should I grey-out the whole day if none of my resources have businessHours set?

When **businessHours are set** for each of the resources on the specific date
[image]

When **businessHours are not set** for any of the resources on the specific date
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My resource Ruby object was not set properly. Simply checking if businessHours is already set, if not, adding businessHours with **only dow set** for every resource solved my problem.

```
resource_example = { id: my_id, title: my_title, businessHours: { dow: my_daynum } }
```

[image]